# Converting some string elements to int

Tags: java, arrays

I have search all over the net on how to convert two specific elements in an array and was very unlucky about the research

```
package scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeInformation {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    static String[][] info = {{"09-001", "Ja Gb", "100", "10", },
                        {"09-002", "Justine", "200", "20", },
                        {"09-003", "Ja Ja", "150", "15", }};

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.print("     - MENU -\n");
        System.out.print("A. Search Record\nB. Payroll Summary\n------------------\nEnter choice: ");
        String choice = null;
        choice = sc.nextLine();


        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Employee #: ");
            String EmpNum = sc.nextLine();
            SearchRecord(EmpNum);
        }
        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
                PayrollSummary();
            }
        else {
            System.out.print("Invalid input.");
        }
    }

    private static void SearchRecord(String employeeNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] matchedRow = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            String[] oneRow = info[i];
                if (oneRow[0].equals(employeeNumber)) {
                    matchedRow = oneRow;
                    break;
                }
        }
        System.out.print("\nEmployee #:\tEmployee Name\tRate per Hour\tTotal Hours Worked\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < matchedRow.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(matchedRow[i] + "\t\t");
        }
    }

    private static void PayrollSummary() {

        System.out.println("\nEmployee #:\tEmployee Name\tRate per Hour\tTotal Hours Worked\tGross Pay");

        int intArr[] = new int[info.length];
        int r = 0;
        while ( r < info.length) {
            int c = 0;
            while ( c <= r ) {
                if ( c == 2 ) {
                    intArr[c] = Integer.parseInt(info[r][c]);
                if ( c == 3 ) {
                    intArr[c] = Integer.parseInt(info[r][c]);
                }
                }

                c++;
            // How do I multiply index 2 and 3 of Array info and store it in info[r][4]?    
            }

            r++;
        }



    }
}

...
```

Comment: What happens in this code ? are any  exceptions in this code ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `info[r][4] = info[r][3] * info[r][2]` ?

Comment: Do you want to parse values inside info array? If so, keep in mind that parsing e.g "Justine" into int will produce NumberFormatException.

Comment: *[...]store it in info[r][4]?*. Every row of your `info` has a length of 4, so the maximum index is `info[r][3]`.

Comment: @ronk, Yes. I tried that code but no luck.. I got this error "The operator * is undefined for the argument java.lang.string...."

Comment: Do you realise that you haven't asked a question?  You've made a statement of fact, and then posted a large block of code...

Comment: @halex. If you notice there is a comma after the last element. So, there is essentially 5 elements.

Comment: @RohitJain The comma at the end is optional and does not add another element. See http://ideone.com/musbCK for proof

Comment: @halex. Did you just wrote that code? And yes I forgot that thing. :)

Comment: @RohitJain Yes I just wrote it :)

Answer (score 4):

In order to multiply two values represented as Strings you must parse them first.

If you want to parse an arbitrary String into Integer you should keep in mind that it is impossible to parse some Strings e.g "Justine". You must handle NumberFormatException which will be thrown in such case.

```
try{
    Integer myInt = Integer.parseInt(info[x][y]);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    // handle your exception
}
```

Comment: @mill.bartek Thanks a lot it solved my problem.. i just wonder why do i have to handle numberformatexception? 

I made my code like this and got the correct output for the program

`int arrR = 0;
int arrC = 0;
int r = 0;

while ( r < info.length) {

    try {

 arrR = Integer.parseInt(info[r][2]);

 arrC = Integer.parseInt(info[r][3]);

 } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

   System.out.print("NumberFormatException");
 }
 info[r][4] = String.valueOf(arrR * arrC);
 r++;
 }
for(String[] view : info) {
for( String summary : view) {
System.out.print(summary + "\t\t");
}
System.out.println();
}`

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the values provided inside your array will always be Strings that are capable of being parsed into int (e.g "10", "45") then you may skip error handling.

Comment: Handling error could keep your application working in correct way independently of input provided to parseInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
class Testing  
{  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
    System.out.println(isNumeric("123"));  
    System.out.println(isNumeric("123.45"));  
    System.out.println(isNumeric("$123"));  
    System.out.println(isNumeric("123x"));  
  }  
  public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
  {  
    try  
    {  
      double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
    }  
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
    {  
      return false;  
    }  
    return true;  
  }  
}
```

this way you can parse through your array and if it is a NumberFormatException it is not a number.